# Why is the current for \$i(t)\$ \$5mA\$, not \$5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8m}}\$ mA?

Tags: capacitor, current, homework, transient, voltage-source

Close the switch of  the circuit, and  it is in the steady state. We open the switch at \$t=t_1\$ suddenly.  What is the value of \$i(t_1)\$?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC82G3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The solution for this is as below:

\$V_{R2}=120\times \frac{2}{4+2}=40V\$, so \$i(t)=\frac{40}{6k+2k}=5mA\$

I understand the formula above, when  \$C_1\$ is most fully charged,\$C_1\$ will become like an open circuit, so \$V_{C1}=V_{R2}=40V\$

However, I found [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capdis.html) that the formula  of discharge current  from the capacitor is:

\$i_c=\frac{V}{R}e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}=\frac{40}{8k}e^{-\frac{t}{8k \times 100\mu}}=5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8}} \$ mA.

I know we can see "almost fully" charged as a voltage source, just like the formula from the solution, but I think my method should be right, too.
  Why is the answer for \$i(t)\$ \$5mA\$, not \$5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8m}}\$ mA?

Comment: Maybe they ask about the current value at time t1. And they don't care about the transient. Also, notice that the time constant is 0.8s not 0.8ms. Also from which book, you have all these exercises?

Comment: No, the steady state current into R2 is 20 mA i.e. \$\dfrac{40\text{ volts}}{2\text{ k}\Omega}\$.

Comment: You open the switch at t1, and wish to know the current at the instant just after the switch has opened, so you do not need a general solution for any time t1+ (Which would be an exponential). The current at time t1 (just after the switch has opened) is simply 40V (Voltage on the cap) / (6k+2k) = 5mA.  If you wanted current at any time after T1 then you would need the exponential version, but note that the time in the exponential form would be (t-t1). Note that e^0 = 1, so providing you use the correct start time, the exponential and the simple t1 expression are the same.

Comment: @DanMills Why not use the answer box?

Comment: @Huisman, If I am going to write an answer, I would rather do it properly, and I have not got the time to do that right now.

Comment: You can also use \$5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8}}\$ mA and substitute t=0.

Comment: @Andyaka I Think when the switch opened,the capacitor will begin discharging ,so i understand why will the answer tell me the i(t) is 5mA

Comment: @G36 Oh yes! you are right,sorry  about that,and maybe your explanation about current is 5mA is right!

Comment: @shineele I didn't quite get the gist of your question - I thought you were trying to calculate the steady state value - then you've re-written it and it becomes clearer.

Comment: @Andyaka now i know why is current is \$5mA\$,not \$ 5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8}}\$mA,because   \$ 5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8}}\$ is a curve,but the question ask what is the i when the switched is opened suddenly,so it should be a point,not a curve

Comment: @shineele I think you're making an incorrect antithesis. \$5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8}} \$mA **does** hold. The current **is** \$5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8}} \$mA: the question asks for the value at \$ t=0\$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're stating a paradox.

\$ 5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8}} \text{ mA} \$**does** hold, but the question asks you to evaluate it for \$t=0\$.

So, the answer is 
$$ 5e^{-\frac{t}{0.8}}|_{t=0} \text{ mA} = 5e^{-\frac{0}{0.8}} \text{ mA} = 5 \text{ mA}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the question is asking for \$i(t_1)\$, not \$i(t)\$. That is, the question is asking for the value of the current at a specific instant of time, not as a function of time.